# How to populate second list based on first automaticaly?

Tags: angular

I have ngFor:

```
   <div class="ui-g" *ngFor="let orderTracking of orderTrackings"
```

Inside i have idependet list:

```
<select  [ngModel]="orderTracking.destinationfromCode" (ngModelChange)="orderTracking.destinationfromCode = $event">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option *ngFor="let destination of groupDestinations" [value]="destination.code"  [selected]="orderTracking.destinationfromCode == destination.code">{{destination.displayname}}</option>
```

```
  <select  [ngModel]="orderTracking.destinationtoCode" (ngModelChange)="orderTracking.destinationtoCode = $event">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option *ngFor="let destination of destinationsTo" [value]="destination.code"  [selected]="orderTracking.destinationtoCode== destination.code">{{destination.displayname}}</option>
</select>
```

I have two cases: First case is when user click on first dropdown to populate second based on what he choose from fist. Im done that like this:

```
 <select  [ngModel]="orderTracking.destinationfromCode" (ngModelChange)="orderTracking.destinationfromCode = $event" (click)="selectGroup(orderTracking.destinationfromCode)">
```

But problem is when user already have values for both dropdown list. How can i populate select both of them. Right now it just populate first and select value for first dropdown, but second is not yet populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use 2 way data binding for both of the dropdowns. Then use the `change` event on the first dropdown.

```
// component.html
<select [(ngModel)]="orderTracking.destinationfromCode" (change)="selectGroup(orderTracking)">
    ....
</select>
<select [(ngModel)]="orderTracking.destinationtoCode">
    ....
</select>

// component.ts
selectGroup(order){
    // order.destinationtoCode = someValue;
}
```

This ensures that if both items are set they will be set in the select dropdown. Also if you change the first select, it will update the second select.

Comment: problem is that (change) not call selectGroup method, i tried and change and modelChange

Comment: @None the change event is not called on option select? Do you get any errors

Comment: no..i added console log in method but i dont get anything...i even added settimeout to see maybe data is late but same

Comment: when i change first select its working but "on load" when i get data first time is not working

Comment: @None ah I see. Do you mean `destinationfromCode` is populated, but `destinationtoCode` is not? in which case you expect the change event to set `destintaiontoCode` based on `destinationfromCode` on load

Comment: yes, destinationfromCode is populated, i want to call method selectGroup where i pass destinationfromCode  to get data for second dropdown and if there is orderTracking.destintaiontoCode to get populated  second dropdown

Comment: Problem is that selectGroup method on change is not firing "on load"

Comment: @None so change & ngModelChange do not fire on load. So if you need `destinationtoCode` to be populated based on `destinationfromCode` on load, you should manually set `destinationtoCode` when you receive the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161135/discussion-between-none-and-llai).